# Static when using USB-C PD2 adapter to audio interface into phone

Tags: audio-interfaces, video, feedback, android, adapters

Does anyone have a suggested setup to get audio from a USB-C audio interface directly into the USB-C audio input of their phone via camera app?

I have a USB-C male (plugged into my Samsung S20) to USB-A female (plugged into my Motu M2) and USB-C female (which has PD2 power delivery. I've tried plugging it into multiple sources including 100W chargers attached to a pure sine wave UPS) adapter. I've tried to use this adapter to get power and audio from my XLR Shure SM7B, but when I do, I'm getting static on any phone I try. It is powering the Motu M2 and the mic and I can get audio into the phone, but the persistent static is unacceptable.

The mic works beautifully when the the Motu M2 is plugged directly into my desktop computer via USB-C male to USB-C male. But I want to record to my phone's camera app, and not use my computer as a pass-through, have to use proprietary recording software on Android, or record onto a separate device and sync audio later.

I've tried plugging the audio interface directly into the phone via a USB-C male to USB-C male cable, but the phone kind of freaks out, not knowing what power mode it should be in (I think maybe it can't power the audio interface even if I manually set it to power the external device). I've also tried different adapters which also have USB-C PD2 and still get the static.

I'm using 100W rated cables with fast fast data transfer. Samsung support requested I clear caches, which didn't help.

Edit: I realize it may be relevant to mention I don't believe either of my hubs advertise having pass-through charging. Supposedly, this is only necessary if I want the host device (phone) to charge the slave device (audio interface), which is unnecessary and power delivery 2 is all I should need which should allow the PD2 USB-C charger to power both the host and the slave. I guess that could be the source of the static though.